# issue with set radio button using data from mySQL database

Tags: jquery

I have a form with few elements, including a radio button for gender. There are two buttons in the form, one read data from mySQL database to fill form for editing while the other updates the database data after editing.

I can update database correctly and also can fill in values for all elements correctly except radio button.

The problem is the radio button can be set correctly first time. However, once I update data, it couldn't be set using data from database.

Here is the code. Appreciate.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   url: "databaseController.php",
   data: disdata,
   cache: false,
   error: function(response){},
   success: function(response){
$("#txt_mrn").val(response['patientMRN']);
$("#txt_initial").val(response['patientName']);
$("#txt_bithdate").val(response['DOB']);
$("input[name=rd_gender][value='" + response['gender'] + "']").attr('checked', 'checked');
} // end of success;
});//end of ajax;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
First check whether data you posted after updating gender is correct as per input given.
Second check Database fields that properly stores the values as per given input.
Last Check data you get from database after updating is correctly fetched N display in the page or not .
```

-
Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I looked at database table and each of the three steps you mentioned worked fine. The only thing that didn't work was radio button. My final solution is replaced the radio buttons with exclusive check boxes and the solution works.

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with another solution, using radio button index as the value of a button. In the html file it looks like this

Male
 Female

Then in the js file, the radio button is set as follows,
$("input[name=rd_gender]")[response['gender']].checked = true;

It works great.